# Is the fundamental group of a non-semi-locally simply connected space uncountable?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring is uncountable, so I would think you can argue it injects into such a space, but I think that would rely on some condition like having a countable neighborhood basis.

Comment: What is your question ?The one in the title, or something about Hawaiian earrings ?

Comment: The one in the title

Comment: What about a wedge of uncountably many circles?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri : well this has an uncountable fundamental group, so it can't really answer the question

Comment: Since it's not semi-locally simply connected, then every open neighbourhood $(U, x_0)$ of the basepoint would contain some essential loop $\gamma_U$.  Then I feel like you want to find some set $\Lambda$ of neighbourhoods such that $\gamma_U \nsim \gamma_U'$ for each $U\neq U' \in \Lambda$, and such that $\cap_{U\in \Lambda} U = \{ x_0 \}$. If this is possible, then you might be able to use these $\gamma_U$ to construct uncountably many elements of the fundamental group. Not sure if any of this works, just an idea.

Comment: @Max, right, I misread the question.

Comment: I wonder if you can construct a counterexample with something like the cone on the Hawaiian earring, but where you glue a cell that identifies the loop going around the circle with radius $1/n$ to some multiple of the loop going around the circle with radius $1/(n+1)$ (or maybe radius $1/(n-1)$. If you do the gluing right, the fundamental group could be countable.

Comment: I believe I can show it from the statement "A loop that is homotopic to a loop in every neighborhood of the basepoint is trivial." I only know how to prove this new statement for a first countable space, and I think it might not be true in general. I think a counterexample might come from using some well ordering of the reals to come up with a Hawaiian earring with uncountably many loops and then attaching disks like @JohnPalmieri wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposed counterexample to my own question:

Let $P$ be an ordered set with such that there is no order preserving function $f$ from the natural numbers that has the property that for any element $x \in P$ there is an integer $y$ such that $x \leq f(y)$.

Put a topology on $X=P\cup \{*\}$ by declaring as a basis the individual points in $P$ and the sets containing $*$ such that there is an element $x \in P$ in the set and that if $x \leq y$, then $y$ is in the set. If $P$ were the natural numbers this would be the set $\{0\}\cup\{1/n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the subspace topology.

Take the reduced suspension of $X$ where the basepoint is $*$ and attach a disk from the arc corresponding to the element $x \in P$ to the arc corresponding to $y \in P$ if $x < y$. Call this space $X'$.

I claim $X'$ is not semi-locally simply connected. Any neighborhood around the basepoint contains some circle corresponding to some element $x \in P$. It is pretty clear that the loop obtained by traversing this circle once can only be contracted by moving toward the basepoint through these arcs we added. However, a homotopy can only take us through countably many of these arcs so by the condition on $P$ this homotopy cannot end at the basepoint, so the loop is not trivial.

The fundamental group is also not uncountable because it's pretty clear the loops corresponding to the elements of $P$ have to be the building blocks, but there cannot be infinite sequences of them like in the Hawaiian earring because by the condition on $P$ these loops are not approaching the basepoint. In fact, I think that the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the loop corresponding to some element of $P$.

Again this is only a sketch, please dissect the argument because I would like it to be the case the titular question has an affirmative answer.

Comment: I believe the key idea is that there is no countable neighborhood basis at $*$ otherwise one could be used to show that there are sequences of loops that approach the basepoint and so correspond to loops, and these are uncountable.

Comment: Looks right to me.  To make the arguments rigorous, I think you can show that any map from an interval (or a square, etc) to $X'$ has image contained in the subspace which involves only finitely many elements of $P$ (first reduce to a countable subset of $P$ by a separability argument, and then reduce to a finite subset using a compactness argument).  But if you look at the subspact of $X'$ involving only some finite subset of $P$, it's just a finite CW-complex and everything is easy to verify.

Comment: Note that the ordering on $P$ is not actually necessary.  You can just attach disks between the arcs for all $x,y\in P$, and let neighborhoods of $\{*\}$ in $X$ be cocountable sets.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I don't actually use the ordering anywhere.